# How can I get textures from Blender Render into Cycles?

Tags: modeling, texturing, export

If I made a model with lots of textures in Blender Render and then wanted to use the model in Cycles with all the textures in place, is there a way to export it from Blender Render with the texture data and then import it into Cycles?

Comment: You will need to manually re-create the materials. :( I think

Comment: :( I wish there was some format that had texture data in it.

Comment: @ThomBlairIII obj does, I believe (it's stored in a separate .mtl file)..

Comment: well fbx and obj (obj to some extent) can export basic materials from blender internal